# SSRS 2008 wordwrapping issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, word-wrap

i am using SSRS 2008 and currently I am facing wordwrapping issues.

In report I am placing a table and some 6 columns.

My report size is A4 landscape.

When running the report,one of the column has a large value without any spaces,the column was not wrapping up,so I changed the layout to A3 landscape and the wrapping started working..

Is there any relation to wordwrap and page size?

And sometimes when I provide dynamic sort to column,the wordwrap is not working..

And this wordwrapping is happening very slow in IE browser and sometimes on refresh only the wrap is happening..

Comment: what do you mean by "the wordwrap is not working"?

Comment: I meant wordwrapping issues,like when the report is in A4 landscape,wrapping of column not occuring ,but when i change to A3 the wrap is happening.

Comment: Is text bleeding over into other columns? A screenshot would be a help.

Comment: No;its not bleeding over to other columns,the column just expands in length (rather than word wrapping).I am using a table in the Report and not a Matrix(which has the property to grow horizontal)

Comment: Update on the issue:The wordwrap is happening only on refresh after the first request.Is this has something to do with browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like the issue might be that the content for your report might be bigger for the page size you've fit.  A3 is signifigantly larger than A4.  what you should try is getting the content of the report to fit in an 8 1/2 x 11 size (minus a 1 inch margin so it's really 6 1/2 x 9) in the designer.